# Simple F64 simulations with the rtx 3080

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, montecarlo

I recently bought a RTX 3080 mainly for gaming. But I also do a little bit of monte carlo simulations for quantum physics, even if it is not my primary occupation. And would like to try them on the RTX 3080. However i heard that the 3080 comes with F32 precision and not F64 like the titan RTX and the quadro series, if i'm not mistaking. Is there a way to enable F64 computations (if yes it should decrease the speed by 2 or more?). I'm really new to all this field (GPU computation and architecture) so feel free to give any advice.
Thanks!emphasized text

Comment: "Last but not least, those interested in double-precision capabilities (FP64) of consumer Ampere need to know there are two dedicated FP64 cores per SM, or exactly 1/64th of FP32. The ratio also defines FP64 performance on a GPU-by-GPU basis, so if a card has, say, 30 TFLOPS of FP32 it will have 469 GFLOPS of FP64."

Comment: All NVIDIA GPUs of the past dozen years support double-precision (DP) computation. It is just that the consumer cards often have low throughput of double-precision operations, with the RTX 3080 specifically providing about 400 DP GFLOPS to 450 DP GFLOPS depending on actual clock frequency (all modern GPUs use dynamic clocking schemes that adjust operating frequency continuously based on a variety of factors such as temperature and power consumption).